# Issue grabbing div with ID from the MasterPageFile using C# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

The aspx file I am using (We can call this page "A") has a MasterPageFile.

In the actual MasterPageFile there is a div.  I need to be able to grab this div and use it in the C# code behind page of Page "A".

So here is my question:

How do I grab the div from the MasterPageFile and use it in the C# code behind file of page "A"?

Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: You don't. If you need to do that, you need to move the section out of the master page.

Comment: That sounds good but the div I need is used for all of the popups in the entire program.  I dont think that is feasible.  There's over 40 other pages that use the same MasterFilePage.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Label label1 = Page.Master.FindControl("Label1") as Label;

Answer (score 0):

You are free to grab any control in the master page from child page code

So, say in master page, we have this:

```
    <div id="DivInMaster" runat="server">


    </div>
```

So, in the child page, you can do this:

```
        HtmlGenericControl mydiv = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.Master.FindControl("DivInMaster");

        mydiv.InnerHtml = "<b>Hello world</b>";
```